# how to change config server uri dynamically using OS environment

Tags: spring-boot, environment-variables, spring-cloud-config, setx

I have a `spring config server` and `spring config client`. In client I have set `spring.cloud.config.uri` to `http://localhost:8888` but I want to change it to some other uri say `http://example.com:8888` in windows using OS environment with `setx`. so I ran

```
setx spring.cloud.config.uri "http://example.com:8888"
```

but when I run my `spring config client` it's still trying to read from `localhost` . As per [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config) link my `spring.cloud.config.uri` in `bootstrap.yml` should get override by what i set with `OS environment` but it didn't. Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### setx

`setx` adds the variable but doesn't make it available in the current shell ([as explained here](https://superuser.com/questions/916649/what-is-the-difference-between-setx-and-set-in-environment-variables-in-windows)):

> setx modifies the value permenantly, which affects all future shells,
>   but does not modify the environment of the shells already running. You
>   have to exit the shell and reopen it before the change will be
>   available, but the value will remain modified until you change it
>   again.

Just make sure you are runnning from a newly opened shell window.

I suggest you use `set spring.cloud.config.uri=http://example.com:8888` just for the sake of testing.

#### Check if the environment variable is present

You may add the following as the very first line your `main` method:

```
System.out.println(System.getenv("spring.cloud.config.uri"));
System.out.println(System.getenv("SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI"));
```

### Variable name with underscore

Windows supports environment variables with dots, so it should be ok for you. This isnt the case for pretty much all the other OS. Just so you know, spring supports variable name with *underscores* (as explained in the link you provided):

> If you use environment variables rather than system properties, most
>   operating systems disallow period-separated key names, but you can use
>   underscores instead (e.g. SPRING_CONFIG_NAME instead of
>   spring.config.name).